# Bounds on $\Big(\lambda_{\max}(uu')\Big)^2$ where $u\in \mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: matrices, solution-verification, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Bounds on $\Big(\lambda_{\max}(uu')\Big)^2$ where $u\in \mathbb{R}^n$.

Is the following bound correct?
\begin{align*}
\Big(\lambda_{\max}(uu')\Big)^2
&\leq \Big(\max_i \sum^n_{j=1} |u_iu_j|\Big)^2 &&\text{By Gershgorin circle theorem}\\
&\leq \Big(|n|\max_i u_i^2\Big)^2\\
&=|n|^2\max_i u_i^4\\
\end{align*}

Any tigher bounds?

Comment: Huh? $u u^T$ has two eigenvalues, $0$ and $\|u\|^2$.

Comment: Thanks. Can you explain a bit more. I am a rookie!

Comment: $\|u u ^T x \| \le  \|u\| |u^T x| \le \|u\|^2 \|x\|$. Hence $\|u u^T\| \le \|u\|^2$. Choosing $x=u$ shows equality.

Comment: It seems to result in the same bound as mine tho. $(\sum^n_{i=1}u_i^2)^2\leq |n|^2\max u_i^4$. I suppose it's tigher. Happy to accept it if you put in the ans section.

Comment: Not sure how you jumped to that conclusion, take $u=(1,0)$, then your bound gives $4$, whereas the correct bound gives $1$.

Comment: I meant your bound implied mine. Bad wording.